# Asymptotic distribution of MLE

Tags: normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood

It has been well understood that the asymptotic distribution of `MLEs` of model parameters are jointly normally distributed.

But in many cases, the true value of model parameter is bounded. For example, to estimate the failure rate `rho`, the MLE is total number of failures divided by total number of items.

So in this case, how the normality assumption of `MLE` of the failure probability can be valid, given that `normal distribution` can take any values including negative values?

Comment: Asymptotic Normallity gives us an approximate distribution for the MLE when $n < \infty$. Under suitable conditions, as $n \to \infty$, $var (\hat{\rho}) \to 0$. This means that for sufficiently large $n$, the weight given to invalid values (like negative values) becomes negligible. This is an approximate result, but it is a highly practical approximation in many circumstances. If the approximation is not good enough for you; you will need to do further work to derive an exact distribution of the MLE of interest

Comment: @jcken, why not post the comment as an answer? Bogaso, `this font` is for code. *Italics* and **boldface** are some good options for emphasis in a regular text.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thanks for your suggestion. However I don't see any universally accepted criteria to use `this` only for code. I found several places where `this` style is used to highlight **mathematical terms** also

Comment: It depends on how universal we want to go, but at least you would hardly find such posts among active, high-reputation users. Using code formatting for noncode makes it harder to read because the font itself signals the content is code while the content contradicts that. It is not just about aesthetics but also about functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Asymptotic Normallity gives us an approximate distribution for the MLE when $n < \infty$

Under suitable conditions, as $n \to \infty$, $Var(\hat{\rho}) \to 0$. This means that for sufficiently large $n$, the weight given to invalid values (like negative values) becomes negligible. This is an approximate result, but it is a highly practical approximation in many circumstances. If the approximation is not good enough for you; you will need to do further work to derive an exact distribution of the MLE of interest.

An alternative approach, if you want a strictly valid MLE distribution is to construct the MLEs on an unconstrained scale, for example, since $\rho > 0$ you may prefer to form an MLE for $\log \rho$